# Using localStorage to return the last search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm using React right now and I'm trying to get my localstorage to update a state once the event handles a return on search and then hold that state until the next search is completed. Right now I can't figure out where to put an event handler that triggers the correct state and holds the correct value.

```
    const useStateWithLocalStorage = localStorageKey => {
      const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
        localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey) || ''
      );
      React.useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, value);
      }, [value]);
      return [value, setValue];
    };
    export default function App() {
      const [value, setValue] = useStateWithLocalStorage(
        'myValueInLocalStorage'
      );
      const onChange = event => setValue(event.target.value);
      const [state, setState] = useState({
        message: 'test deploy',
        results: [],
        value: '',
      });
    ...
```

and where I'm trying to implement the event handler

````
    export default function SearchAppBar(props) {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
      const { onClick } = props;
    ...
            <InputBase
              onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
            <Button onClick={() => onClick(searchTerm)}> Search </Button>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Hereby my solution. I've created an `useLocalStorage` function that stores and gets or sets items in the local storage and holds them in its own state:

```
import React from "react";

export const useLocalStorage = (key, initialValue) => {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = React.useState(() => {
    try {
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return initialValue;
    }
  });

  const setValue = value => {
    try {
      setStoredValue(value);
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return [storedValue, setValue];
};

export default useLocalStorage;
```

For the searchBar component I've used a forwardRef to access the value of the input inside our higher component `App`. The `newSearch` function and `searchTerm` variable are destructured off the props. The placeholder holds the stored value in localStorage, which is `searchTerm`:

```
export const SearchAppBar = React.forwardRef(
  ({ newSearch, searchTerm }, ref) => {
    return (
      <>
        <input ref={ref} type="text" placeholder={searchTerm} />
        <button onClick={newSearch}> Search </button>
      </>
    );
  }
);
```

Inside the main `App` component I'm using our useLocalStorage function hook to get and set the search. Inside `newSearch` I'm updating the search term by calling our hook with the value of the forwarded input ref.

```
export default function App() {
  const ref = React.createRef();

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useLocalStorage(
    "search",
    "Not searched yet"
  );

  const newSearch = () => {
    setSearchTerm(ref.current.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SearchAppBar ref={ref} newSearch={newSearch} searchTerm={searchTerm} />
      <p>Last search: {searchTerm}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Hope this is a workable solution for you.

Please find a code snippet here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-sunset-8fqtm?file=/src/index.js:387-773

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach used by redux to handling the states on react. I use redux with redux-persist library to save the state instead of localStorage. If your project grows and you need to work with more complex states, it could help you.